# When will the break of iwlwifi be fixed in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: kernel, 19.10, iwlwifi

Kernel 5.3.0.42 broke iwlwifi in Ubuntu 19.10. This is well known. It has been fixed in 5.5 (see https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206329).

My question is, will this be fixed in 19.10? Will kernel 5.5 ever appear in 19.10, or is this going to wait until Ubuntu 20? Will it be back-ported to kernel 5.3, in order to fix what someone broke?

Answer (score 2):

Kernel 5.5 won't be packaged for Ubuntu 19.10 for the simple reason that 19.10 will reach End Of Life (EOL) in July 2020, a mere few months from now.

Ubuntu 20.04 is currently running Kernel 5.4.21, and will be released with some newer version of 5.4...but still 5.4. Look for a newer (like 5.6 or newer) with Ubuntu 20.10.

While it may be "well known," and bugzilla has the bug as a High priority, I have not been able to find any record of any Ubuntu participants asking the Ubuntu Kernel team to patch 5.4 for this bug. Ubuntu works best when the community participates.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into how to ask for it.

Comment: I've reported it now.

Comment: Thanks @Leonard. For others reference https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1871134